# mouseover.js doesn't work in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have an error somewhere, but I can figure it out. I have a mouseover.js script that is supposed to create a nice effect on a page - on mouse-over an image the image will switch from grayscale to a colored version.

The script is loaded in header.php like this:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' );?>
    /js/mouseover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The full script is here: http://pastebin.com/yeBtedcg

The page where this script should function is here: http://www.capital-restaurants.com/web/menu (the menu-images should all be in grayscale and only on mouse-over they should reveal colors).

I know the script works fine because I used it before, but now I can't seem to find out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is www.domain.com and your image is loading from domain.com, so the canvas.getImageData can't work for security reasons, change your images to the same domain.

Comment: Could you explain please how can I change the domain? I'm quite a beginner in javascript.

Comment: cross-origin restrictions mean that the 1) domain 2) protocol and 3) port must match for both the origin (your page) and the resource (your image). try moving the image referenced by `getImageData()` onto `http://www.capital-restaurants.com/`

Comment: i know this must sound stupid, but how do I identify the image referenced by getImageData() ? i mean, all the necessary images are already on the capital domain.

Comment: @GeorgeGrigorita change the src to the www.domain ... src="http//www.capital-restaurants.com/ ... .jpg"

Answer (score 0):

mouseover.js is being loaded so you'r problem isn't with the WordPress integration. Figured I'd note, however, that you're not really going about script addition the correct way for a WordPress plugin. Take a look at [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Here's a helper function:

```
function add_static_js_asset( $asset_name, $asset_path, $dependencies = false, $version = null, $in_footer = false ) {

        $dependencies = ( is_bool( $dependencies ) ) ? $dependencies : false;
        $version = ( !empty( $version ) ) ? $version : '0.1';
        $in_footer = ( is_bool( $in_footer ) ) ? $in_footer : false;

        if ( empty( $asset ) ) {
                return false;
        }                                                                                                      

        wp_enqueue_script( "{$asset_name}_script", $asset_path), $dependencies, $version, $in_footer );

}
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't use the wp_enqueue_script. Bad habits don't die easily. Will fix this, thanks.

Comment: it's somewhat pedantry to insist on enqueue but it could help if you want to ensure no duplicated loads, etc.